# jQuery Autocomplete from example code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I could not find an answer in any other question with the same problem.
I'm trying to use jQuery Autocomplete, but it simply does not do anything:

```
$(function(){
    $("#pj-filter").change(function(){
        window.location.href = "?project_filter=" + $(this).val();
    });
    $("#user-filter").change(function(){
        window.location.href = "?project_filter=false&user_filter=" + $(this).val();
    });
    $("#add-task").click(function(e){
        Popup.loading();
        request("task_form", {}, function(response){
            Popup.finish();
            Popup.display(response);
            $("input#name").focus();
            $(".date-input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', firstDay: 1 });
            /*var projects = <?php echo json_encode($projects); ?>;
            $("#project").autocomplete({
                source: projects
            });*/
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
            $("#save-task").click(function(){
                Popup.loading();
                request("save_task", {
                    name: $("input#name").val(),
                    status: $("select#status").val(),
                    description: $("textarea#description").val(),
                    due_date: $("input#due_date").val(),
                    type: $("select#type").val(),
                    safeID: $("input#safeID").val(),
                    project: $("input#project").val()
                }, function(response){
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The code is from the examples on jQuerys homepage.
The strange thing is that if I view the code in Chrome:

```
<input type="text" id="project" maxlength="64" value="" 
       class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

The input has the class `ui-autocomplete-input`, but still the autocomplete does not work.

I use jQuery 3.1.1 and jQuery-UI 1.12.1
The same code in jsfiddle works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/yn1Lo5cm/

```js
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$("#project").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="project" maxlength="64" value="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: try;
`$document.ready(function() { 
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
});`

Comment: works for me when I created your snippet - you likely need to execute the initial code after the element is available

Comment: The JSFiddle is defaulting to "ONLOAD" - you need to write your own onload as @azola showed - view-source of JSFiddle shows `window.onload=function(){
var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
...        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });`

Comment: In the meantime I also created a snippet. And it works properly.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No, full clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can be very sure that there is no issue with the code. One thing here, what do you mean by the autocomplete *does not work* ?? The following line you said is interesting:

> The input has the class ui-autocomplete-input, but still the
>   autocomplete does not work.

To make it work we need the [jqueryui css](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css).

I am telling this as the link to the css was not there in the fiddle. Is it the case?

**EDIT:**

Another thing to note here:
I believe the autocomplete HTML attribute is related to browsers automatically completing the text from previous uses, not related to the jQueryui functionality.

Comment: Thank you. You solved the problem :D The whole form was on a popup window and the autocomplete list was behind this window with lower z-index.

Comment: Wow! never thought of that scenario!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have autocomplete set to off try `<input type="text" id="project" maxlength="64" value="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on">`

Comment: Still works with the autocomplete=off - see the snippet I did from his code

Comment: Yes, it is not the problem.

Comment: I believe the autocomplete HTML attribute is related to browsers automatically completing the text from previous uses, not related to the jQueryui functionality.